# Getting a syntax error when trying to join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have created the following tables:

USER TABLE

```
user_id (primary key)
account_created (date)
email (varchar)
usage_count (number)
```

PRODUCT TABLE

```
product_id (primary key)
product (varchar) (values include “iPhone”, “Android”, “Windows”)
users_supported (number) (users supported notes: some phones can support group calls up to 1000 users, some can only support normal calls of 2 users)
```

USAGE TABLE

```
usage_id (primary key)
product_id (foreign key)
user_id (foreign key)
usage_date (date)
purchase_call (number) (can be a 0, 2, 4, 6, or 10 min call)
usage_winnings (number) (when users use their minutes, sometimes they will randomly earn cash back)
computer_usage (binary value) (users can link the phone to a computer, and make calls through their computer, similar to google voice)
```

I want to write a select statement with the following constraints:

1. Time frame between 2014 and 2016
2. % of calls made for 2 users
3. % of purchased minutes used for only 2 users
4. Only in the first 30 days after a user created their account

In each year between 2014 and 2016, what percentage of calls and purchased calls were for only 2 users in each user's first 30 days after they created their account.

I have been practicing joins and what I have is:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.users_supported = 2)/COUNT(p.users_supported), SUM(CASE WHEN users_supported = 2 THEN us.purchase_call ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN users_supported <> 2 THEN us.purchase_call ELSE 0 END)
FROM USERS u
JOIN USAGE us ON u.user_id = us.user_id
JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.product_id = us.product_id
WHERE u.account_created >= '2014-01-01'
AND u.account_created <= '2016-12-31'
AND u.account_created <= u.account_created + 30
```

I have several errors right now - the percentages are not coming out correct and the account created with 30 days constraint is causing an error that breaks the whole query. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry my university's network is down so I cannot connect to my database and get a sample set, I can try to create one here mannually.

Comment: @ogk write code at site like [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler), save it and share with us

Comment: What is the syntax error?  Exact error message?) (Per title there is one right?)  but then it says 2 tables and this has 3... so *Shrug*  on first blush the problem with the results is that you have a 1:M and a M:1 relationship which is artificially inflating the counts of the values your'e looking at.  You need to get the counts though an inline view before you join otherwise the %'s will be off..

Comment: @xQbert yes the syntax error is in the first line with the `select` statement

Comment: and the error states? and what data type is us.purchase_call? and p.users_Supported?

Comment: @xQbert my schools network is down so I can't get the exact error. But `purchase_call` and `users_supported` are both an `INT`

Comment: shouldn't numerator COUNT(p.users_supported = 2) be sum instead? weather you count a 1 or a 0 it's still adding 1.  but if you sum a 1 or a 0 it makes a difference. and is u.account_Created a date or datetime datatype?

Comment: @xQbert `users_supported` isnt a binary int, it can be 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what database you are using...

First thing I notice is that

AND u.account_created <= u.account_created + 30

is always true.  I think you want the query based on the current date like

AND u.account_created > NOW() - 30

If you are using sql server then you could use the datediff function and check for a result < 30

Since it was pointed out that you tagged this question mysql then using TIMESTAMPDIFF will work.  Here is an example showing the syntax and the use of the NOW() function.

```
mysql> select TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,NOW(),'20161206');
+-------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,NOW(),'20161206') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                 -17 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: question is tagged with `mysql`

Comment: Hi Wayne I am using a mysql server

Comment: *You did not state what database you are using...* -- His question is tagged `mysql`.

Comment: sorry, didn't check that.